# Is there a way to symbolically invert a piecewise function

Tags: equation-solving, piecewise, inverse

I have a piecewise function that is continuous and strictly monotonic, like this:

```
f[t_] = Piecewise[{{t/4, t < 0}, {t/2, t < 3}, {3/2 + (t - 3)*3, True}}]
```

Now, I would like to get the inverse of that function. I would like an expression like this:

```
fInverse[x_] = Piecewise[{{4*x, x < 0}, {2*x, x < 1.5}, {5/2 + x/3, True}}]
```

(I later want to convert that expression or something derived from it of it to C code that will run on a microprocessor. So I need symbolic result, not a numerical one.)

I have tried `InverseFunction[f]`, but I think it the result is a numerical inverse. I also tried `Solve[f[t] == x, t]`, but it returns no result at all.

`Simplify[Reduce[f[t] == x, t]]` with proper assumptions (`$Assumptions = {t ∈ Reals, x ∈ Reals}`) is promising:

```
(t == 2 x && 0 <= x < 3/2) || (t == 4 x && x < 0) || (6 t == 15 + 2 x && 2 x >= 3)
```

but it's not a piecewise expression.

My next step would be to write a function `piecewiseInvert` that iterates through the alternatives in the `Piecewise` expression, solves each one for `t`, changes the conditions appropriately, and creates a new `Piecewise`, but I'm hoping that there's a simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're on the right track with `Reduce`.  If the domain `Reals` is specified, `Reduce` will return results that can be converted to a `Piecewise` expression straightforwardly.

```
Clear[f];
f[t_] = Piecewise[{{t/4, t < 0}, {t/2, t < 3}, {3/2 + (t - 3)*3, True}}];

invPW[f_] := Evaluate @ Module[{t}, 
  Piecewise[
   List @@ Reduce[# == f[t], t, Reals] /. {cond_ && t == expr_ :> {expr, cond}}]] &;

fInverse = invPW[f]
fInverse[x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One can remove the extraneous `True` case by replacing the last condition by `True`:

```
invPWC[f_] := Evaluate @ Module[{t}, 
     Piecewise[
      ReplacePart[
       List @@ Reduce[# == f[t], t, Reals] /. {cond_ && t == expr_ :> {expr, cond}},
       {-1, -1} -> True]]] &;

fInverse = invPWC[f]
fInverse[x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Note: `Solve` almost does it, also yielding a result that can be converted to `Piecewise` easily.  But it does not include the end points of the intervals when appropriate.

```
Solve[x == f[t], t, Reals]

(* {{t -> ConditionalExpression[2 x, 0 < x < 3/2]},
    {t -> ConditionalExpression[4 x, x < 0]}, 
    {t -> ConditionalExpression[1/6 (15 + 2 x), x > 3/2]}}  *)
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to use `ConditionalExpression` instead of `Piecewise`. For example:

```
InverseFunction /@ {ConditionalExpression[#/4, # <= 0] &, 
                    ConditionalExpression[#/2, 0 <= # <= 3] &, 
                    ConditionalExpression[3/2 + 3 (# - 3), 3 <= #] &}
```

returns

```
{ConditionalExpression[4 #1, #1 <= 0] &, ConditionalExpression[2 #1, 0 <= #1 <= 3/2] &, 
 ConditionalExpression[1/6 (15 + 2 #1), #1 > 3/2] &}
```

which is indeed the inverse, also expressed as a `ConditionalExpression`.

Comment: The expression in question is the result of an integral containing piecewise functions. And I don't think I can calculate that integral using `ConditionalExpression`s. Is there a way to automatically convert a piecewise expression to a set of `ConditionalExpression`s?

Comment: I'm not sure. I guess there must be, but I've never tried to convert.