# Need help understanding the function in linked answer (that symbolically inverts a piecewise function)

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction, pattern-matching, piecewise

[This Answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/35401/34646) provides the following code

```
invPWC[f_] := Evaluate @ Module[{t}, 
 Piecewise[
  ReplacePart[
   List @@ Reduce[# == f[t], t, Reals] /. {cond_ && t == expr_ :> {expr, cond}},
   {-1, -1} -> True]]] &;
```

I get that the `{-1,-1} -> True` replaces the last condition with "True", and I think I get that `#` is being used so that the function doesn't need to define another variable.

What I am most confused about though is the following

> - What is `{cond_ && t == expr_ :> {expr, cond}}` doing?
> - `List @@` is reducing the head of the `Reduce` output with "list", but what is the head of the `Reduce` output?

With regards to my first question, I figure `cond_` and `express_` are defined by `Reduce`, and here we are just accessing them (and replacing them with something?) but I have no idea what they do

With regards to my second question, I tried using `FullForm` on some `Reduce` examples, but sometimes the head seems to be `And`, other times `Or`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's useful to have a test input on hand when taking apart code like the one in the OP.

```
ff = Function[t, Piecewise[{{t/4, t < 0}, {t/2, t < 3}, {3/2 + (t - 3)*3, True}}]];
```

First (with a slight change of variables to help clarify the operations),

```
Reduce[x == ff[y], y, Reals]
   (x <= 0 && y == 4 x) || (0 < x <= 3/2 && y == 2 x) || (x > 3/2 && y == 1/6 (15 + 2 x))
```

This generates a bunch of conditions in [disjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) (DNF), corresponding to the pieces of the function to be inverted.

```
List @@ %
   {x <= 0 && y == 4 x, 0 < x <= 3/2 && y == 2 x, x > 3/2 && y == 1/6 (15 + 2 x)}
```

Here, `Apply[]` (`@@`) converts the disjunction (`Or[]`) into a list of conditions.

```
% /. {cond_ && y == expr_ :> {expr, cond}}
   {{4 x, x <= 0}, {2 x, 0 < x <= 3/2}, {1/6 (15 + 2 x), x > 3/2}}
```

We match each conjunction (`And[]`, `&&`), and extract the pieces required to build a `Piecewise[]` function out of them. Taking the first piece `x <= 0 && y == 4 x` as an example, and using the pattern `cond_ && y == expr_ :> {expr, cond}`, `cond_` corresponds to `x <= 0`, and `expr_` corresponds to `4 x`.

```
ReplacePart[%, {-1, -1} -> True]
   {{4 x, x <= 0}, {2 x, 0 < x <= 3/2}, {1/6 (15 + 2 x), True}}
```

As you mentioned, this just converts the last condition to `True` (corresponding to the "default" case of the `Piecewise[]` function). Finally, this can be fed to `Piecewise[]` directly:

```
Piecewise[%]
   Piecewise[{{4 x, x <= 0}, {2 x, 0 < x <= 3/2}}, (15 + 2 x)/6]
```

The rest of the function with its `(Evaluate[(* stuff *)] &` is just one way to produce a pure function instead of a function with an explicit variable.

---

> With regards to my second question, I tried using `FullForm` on some `Reduce` examples, but sometimes the head seems to be `And`, other times `Or`...

That's actually a weakness of the current approach. The function as currently implemented assumes the output of `Reduce[]` is always DNF. One way to ensure that this is always the case is to use `BooleanConvert[]`, e.g. `BooleanConvert[Reduce[x == ff[y], y, Reals], "DNF"]`.

Comment: I'm still confused on one thing: Why do we need `y=expr_` as opposed to just `expr_` -- for example, we don't have a `y=cond_`.. **Also, This is a really good answer, thanks**.

Comment: Look *carefully* at the structure of e.g. `x <= 0 && y == 4 x`. `y == cond_` does **not** match `x <= 0` (i.e. `MatchQ[x <= 0, y == cond_]` returns `False`). However, `y == 4 x` does match `y == expr_` (i.e. `MatchQ[y == 4 x, y == expr_]` returns `True`), but you *don't* need the `y ==` portion, so you peel out the required piece in the replacement rule.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks